# Permissions problem on bin folder of a newly deployed MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

I have just deployed a new MVC3 app to my hosting provider for the first time.  After a few solved problems, the latest issue is that when I try and access the site, I get the following error:

*Failed to start monitoring changes to '.....\wwwroot\bin' because access is denied.*

I did come across something that suggested that on IIS6, this could be caused by wildcard mapping for the ASP.NET ISAPI module, and this causes a directory watch to unnecessarily be placed on the bin folder, requiring certain unavailable permissions.  I don't know if this possibly extends to IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your IIS user has permissions to the folder.